# You are using an old or stdlib version of json gem

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I've seen the following issue mentioned in another thread a few days ago amongst other problems, but the solution for this issue (to me) didn't seem to be addressed.

I recently ran a test on my Ruby 1.9.2-p290 environment and was presented with the following error when I ran a test script:

```
You are using an old or stdlib version of json gem
Please upgrade to the recent version by adding this to your Gemfile:

gem 'json', '~> 1.7.7'
```

This issue continued when I created a completely fresh Ruby 1.9.3-p392 environment, running on Windows XP (don't ask).  What confuses me is that even when I have json 1.7.7 or 1.8.0 installed (gem list is pasted below), I still get this message when I run my test.  It's not really affecting my test results, but the warning is just rather annoying to see each time.

Which Gemfile do I need to add this version into, and where would it be located?

```
gem list:
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
childprocess (0.3.9)
commonwatir (4.0.0)
ffi (1.8.1 x86-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.2, 0.3)
json (1.8.0, 1.7.7, 1.5.5)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (5.0.0, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.7.3)
rake (10.1.0.beta.3, 10.0.4, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (4.0.1, 3.9.5)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.32.1)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
websocket (1.0.7)
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.7.2)
windows-api (0.4.2)
windows-pr (1.2.2)
```

Comment: Aside: I have seen the same behavior in Ruby 1.9.3-p392.  Also note that this warning comes up even in environments where Bundler is not in use, so the suggestion to edit Gemfile is not applicable.

Comment: the suggestion regarding the gemfile is obviously some other gem developer thinking that 'surely everyone uses bundler'

Comment: Or "surely everyone uses rvm"... or "surely everyone uses Linux"... or "surely everyone uses a terminal that understands ANSI escape codes"... _Sigh._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message is coming from the [`multi_json`](https://rubygems.org/gems/multi_json) gem, and it seems like it could be a bug. [I suggest keeping an eye on this GitHub ticket.](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/issues/116)

If the message is too distressing, you can downgrade `multi_json` to version 1.6.1 to get rid of it. (At least this works for me.)

**UPDATE:**

It looks to me like the root of the problem is that while `multi_json` wants to limit its use of the [`json`](https://rubygems.org/gems/json) and [`json_pure`](https://rubygems.org/gems/json_pure) gems to specific versions, the author of `multi_json` isn't using the [`gem`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-gem) method in his code to activate these versions. (It sounds like he thinks Bundler is the only way to specify versions of gems; it isn't.)

Since `multi_json` will try the [`oj`](https://rubygems.org/gems/oj) and [`yajl-ruby`](https://rubygems.org/gems/yajl-ruby) gems before it tries `json`, using one of those may be the best workaround of all. So you can just install the latest `multi_json` and then install either `oj` or `yajl-ruby` along with it.

Comment: Indeed, a post on the Watir Google Group suggested downgrading multi_json to 1.7.2; this certainly worked for me. (http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/46ef4881fcd71e35)

Comment: "(It sounds like he thinks Bundler is the only way to specify versions of gems; it isn't.)"  +1 for that..  His suggestion in the error message relative to altering a gemfile is more evidence of that sort of thinking.

Comment: I'm running a regular ruby script (i.e. not rails) and hit the error. By installing the 'oj' gem, the error went away for me.

Comment: I've both oj and yajl-ruby installed. But I do still get the message when issuing `vagrant` commands. My vagrant version is `1.3.3`. Why I m getting this message?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
gem update --system 
gem update
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Ruby installation path, for example,
`C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\1.9.1\json`

Open `version.rb` file and update the version detail as shown bellow:
`VERSION = '1.7.7'`

Answer (score 0):

Try running your tests with the `bundle exec` command. This will force your environment to use the gems in `Gemfile.lock`.